# SVG polygon working on desktop but not mobile

Tags: html, svg, mobile, polygon

I'm overlaying two polygons and distorting using filters, hooked to a "generate" button. Works great on desktop. No SVG shows on mobile (Chrome & Safari). Not sure what the issue is. This is my first time working with SVGs in a long time. I don't know if it's the filter that's making it hard to see, but I tried changing to a bright color and it still did nothing. Not sure what to do.

```js
function generateA() {
  function random(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); // The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive
  }

  let x1 = random(0, 830);
  let y1 = random(0, 1080);
  let x2 = random(0, 830);
  let y2 = random(0, 1080);
  let x3 = random(0, 830);
  let y3 = random(0, 1080);
  let x4 = random(0, 830);
  let y4 = random(0, 1080);
  let x5 = random(0, 830);
  let y5 = random(0, 1080);
  let x6 = random(0, 830);
  let y6 = random(0, 1080);
  let x7 = random(0, 830);
  let y7 = random(0, 1080);
  let x8 = random(0, 830);
  let y8 = random(0, 1080);

  let svg = document.getElementById("svg");
  let shape = document.getElementById("polygonA");
  shape.setAttribute("points", `${x1} ${y1}, ${x2} ${y2}, ${x3} ${y3}, ${x4} ${y4}, ${x5} ${y5}, ${x6} ${y6}, ${x7} ${y7}, ${x8} ${y8}`);
  svg.appendChild(shape);
}

function generateB() {
  function random(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); // The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive
  }

  let x1 = random(0, 830);
  let y1 = random(0, 1080);
  let x2 = random(0, 800);
  let y2 = random(0, 200);
  let x3 = random(0, 830);
  let y3 = random(0, 1080);
  let x4 = random(0, 830);
  let y4 = random(0, 1080);
  let x5 = random(0, 830);
  let y5 = random(0, 1080);
  let x6 = random(0, 830);
  let y6 = random(0, 1080);
  let x7 = random(0, 830);
  let y7 = random(0, 1080);
  let x8 = random(0, 830);
  let y8 = random(0, 1080);

  let svg = document.getElementById("svg");
  let shape = document.getElementById("polygonB");
  shape.setAttribute("points", `${x1} ${y1}, ${x2} ${y2}, ${x3} ${y3}, ${x4} ${y4}, ${x5} ${y5}, ${x6} ${y6}, ${x7} ${y7}, ${x8} ${y8}`);
  svg.appendChild(shape);
}

generateA();
generateB();

let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  generateA();
});
let btn2 =
  document.getElementById("btn2");
btn2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  generateB();
});
```

```css
* {
  background-color: burlywood;
}

button {
  display: inline;
  position: static;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.75rem;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="2" width="830" height="1080" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <filter id="round">
     <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
     <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
       <feTurbulence
      type="turbulence"
      baseFrequency="0.01"
      numOctaves="1"
      result="turbulence" />
    <feDisplacementMap
      in2="turbulence"
      in="SourceGraphic"
      scale="300"
      xChannelSelector="R"
      yChannelSelector="G" />
     </filter>
   
    <polygon id="polygonA" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="7" fill="none" filter="url(#round)"/>
    <polygon id="polygonB" stroke="darkolivegreen" stroke-width="7" fill="none" filter="url(#round)"/>    
  </svg>

<button id="btn1">GenerateA</button>
<button id="btn2">GenerateB</button>
```

Comment: Which OS is the mobile? You mention Safari, but Chrome can run on any OS. For Safari I suppose you mean iOS for that. Also which version/release of the OS(s) in question did you test? I have no issues of viewing SVGs on android mobile devices going back several years.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: @GetSet Yes, I have not until this point either. I am using iOS 17.1 and Chrome is up to date. I use chrome on my desktop and it works fine. The only thing that doesn't show up on mobile is the SVG itself.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Even the CodeSnippet works correctly on desktop and not on mobile! I have no clue. I guess it's my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an error in your `<feComposite>` definition.

You're referring to a previous filter result – "goo" – that doesn't exist.

Instead you can refer to the previous "blur" filter result like so:

```
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="blur" operator="atop" />
```

This worked for me on iOS safari

```js
function generateA() {
  function random(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); // The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive
  }

  let x1 = random(0, 830);
  let y1 = random(0, 1080);
  let x2 = random(0, 830);
  let y2 = random(0, 1080);
  let x3 = random(0, 830);
  let y3 = random(0, 1080);
  let x4 = random(0, 830);
  let y4 = random(0, 1080);
  let x5 = random(0, 830);
  let y5 = random(0, 1080);
  let x6 = random(0, 830);
  let y6 = random(0, 1080);
  let x7 = random(0, 830);
  let y7 = random(0, 1080);
  let x8 = random(0, 830);
  let y8 = random(0, 1080);

  let svg = document.getElementById("svg");
  let shape = document.getElementById("polygonA");
  shape.setAttribute("points", `${x1} ${y1}, ${x2} ${y2}, ${x3} ${y3}, ${x4} ${y4}, ${x5} ${y5}, ${x6} ${y6}, ${x7} ${y7}, ${x8} ${y8}`);
  svg.appendChild(shape);
}

function generateB() {
  function random(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); // The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive
  }

  let x1 = random(0, 830);
  let y1 = random(0, 1080);
  let x2 = random(0, 800);
  let y2 = random(0, 200);
  let x3 = random(0, 830);
  let y3 = random(0, 1080);
  let x4 = random(0, 830);
  let y4 = random(0, 1080);
  let x5 = random(0, 830);
  let y5 = random(0, 1080);
  let x6 = random(0, 830);
  let y6 = random(0, 1080);
  let x7 = random(0, 830);
  let y7 = random(0, 1080);
  let x8 = random(0, 830);
  let y8 = random(0, 1080);

  let svg = document.getElementById("svg");
  let shape = document.getElementById("polygonB");
  shape.setAttribute("points", `${x1} ${y1}, ${x2} ${y2}, ${x3} ${y3}, ${x4} ${y4}, ${x5} ${y5}, ${x6} ${y6}, ${x7} ${y7}, ${x8} ${y8}`);
  svg.appendChild(shape);
}

generateA();
generateB();

let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  generateA();
});
let btn2 =
  document.getElementById("btn2");
btn2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  generateB();
});
```

```css
* {
  background-color: burlywood;
}

button {
  display: inline;
  position: static;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.75rem;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 830 1080" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="round">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="blur" operator="atop" />
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01" numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" />
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic" scale="300" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" />
  </filter>

  <polygon id="polygonA" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="7" fill="none" filter="url(#round)" />
  <polygon id="polygonB" stroke="darkolivegreen" stroke-width="7" fill="none" filter="url(#round)" />
</svg>

<button id="btn1">GenerateA</button>
<button id="btn2">GenerateB</button>
```